# ora_rowscn and joins not working together

Tags: join, oracle10g, timestamp

```
SELECT "Rental".*, "Rental".ora_rowscn as TimeStamp FROM "Rental" 
       inner join "UserBranch" on "UserBranch"."fkBranchId" = "Rental"."fkBranchId"
       WHERE "Rental"."IsDeleted"='N' ;
```

This query returns me invalid identifier exception in oracle 10g. I'm a beginner and don't know why the exception is coming. please help. Thank you.

Comment: can you explain why do you need an ora_rowscn, especially in a join? this is not exactly a beginner-level thing

Comment: I wanted to maintain consistency further while updating records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select "Rental".* ,"UserBranch"."fkBranchId", "Rental".ora_rowscn as TimeStamp from "Rental","UserBranch"
        where "UserBranch"."fkBranchId" = "Rental"."fkBranchId"
     and "Rental"."IsDeleted"='N';
```

without joins it works perfectly for me

Comment: ora_rowscn behaviour is ambigious in joins, i explored that. but couldnt come up with some good explanation. If you find one buddy, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get your values with the below query :

```html
SELECT Rental.*, Rental.ora_rowscn as TimeStamp FROM Rental 
inner join UserBranch on UserBranch.fkBranchId = Rental.fkBranchId 
WHERE Rental.IsDeleted='N' ;
```